Turning on adaptive/themed icons on android 12.1
In settings, I can't turn on adaptive/themed icons and setting monet theme. In other roms (I'm on Los) It was available as "beta". How can i turn it on? Device is rooted
Tryed to install another launcher with iconpacks, but launcher is laggy and icons are not very good

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
